# Sorting an array using "points"

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array to make a rank by points but I can't make it work correctly..

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->points, $b->points);
}
usort($teamList, "cmp");  
foreach($teamList as $r)
{
    echo $r->name . " " . $r->points. "<br>";
}
```

I got this with this code:
randomteam*-100
randomteam* -12
randomteam* -12.5
randomteam* -15
randomteam* -15.5
randomteam* -15.5

- Each randomteam is a different team

Comment: Please, provide an array example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing your items as strings. In string terms, `-12.5` is less than `-15` (because `2` is less than `5` and everything up to there is equal.

Instead, just use `return $a->points - $b->points;`.